# FileNotFound exception when trying to create a file (Android)

Tags: android, file

I have this code, just trying to create a new file:

```
// Write to file in thread
    new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Write game data to a file
            String partStr = gameName.replace(" ", "_");
            String fileName = partStr + "_game.txt";

            FileOutputStream gamFile = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            gamFile.write(totItemsStr.getBytes());

        }
    }).start();     // end of thread
```

...but I get a compile error on the openFileOutput command, saying 'Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException'.

If I put a try block around that to catch that exception, the error moves to the write command, saying 'gamFile' cannot be resolved.

Is the problem that I am trying to do this in a thread? Or is it the filename string wrong - should it be some object?

Any ideas gratefully received.

NOTE: 
1. I have tried a TRY block.
2. This error occurs at compilation, BEFORE the code is run (I cannot run it because this compilation error prevents a build).

Comment: create File Object Like File fileobj = new File(fileName); and give the fileObj to FileOutputStream.

Comment: That doesn't work - the first parameter to openFileOutput has to be a string type.

Comment: done write permission in Manifest file ?

Comment: According to the guide, I only need that for external storage - I want to use internal.

Comment: tested your code. works fine put everything in try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the function `openFileOutput`, the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown for multiple reason:

- If the directory where the file is created doesn't exist
- If the file can't be created because of some permission problem

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)) it also states that the name of the file can not contain path separator so check if your path name follows this requirement.

**Edit:**

```
try {
    FileOutputStream gamFile = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    gamFile.write(totItemsStr.getBytes());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // Log your error
}
```

Comment: Thing is, the error is at compile time - I haven't even tried to run the code yet! So fileName is not defined yet. According to the documentation, the call should use internal storage space, so the path is defined internally, no?

Comment: It's because you must use gamFile in the `try` block. It will just be defined in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to catch the **FileNotFoundException** in:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

And check the console for File not found. 
If so the **filename** is not correct, the only other exception you might get is an I/O but that won't be the issue.

Comment: this should be comment not answer

Comment: Sorry! But this is not the way it goes here. You should give solutions as answer. this should have been your comment.

Comment: You were right first time - I had used a try block but did not put all lines in the block. Up-voted your answer (but gave full answer to first answer).

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in try-catch block like this..,

```
new Thread (new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            // Write game data to a file
            String partStr = gameName.replace(" ", "_");
            String fileName = partStr + "_game.txt";

            FileOutputStream gamFile = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            gamFile.write(totItemsStr.getBytes());

        }catch (Exception e){
            // exception found -> do something
            e.printStacktrace();
        }

    }
}).start();     // end of thread
```

it should fix your unhandled FileNotFoundException and 'gamFile' cannot be resolved problem

Comment: did you include 'gamfile.write(toItemStr.getBytes());' in the try-catch block?

Comment: Apologies, my fault - I had not done that - earlier question given the answer.